# How to fetch record from multiple table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I normalize my MySQL database which makes me unable to fetch accurate data, actually I need to get detail information about vendors. I have 5 tables. First table is "vendor" in which I have vendor basic info like name, email, address like shown below:

```
|     id     |     name         |      email        |   address   |
|------------|------------------|----------------------------------
|     1      |    Haris         |  Haris@gmail.com  | Abcd Efgh   |
|------------|------------------|----------------------------------
|     2      |    John          |  john@gmail.com   | Abcd Efgh   |
|------------|------------------|----------------------------------
|     3      |    Chris         | chris@gmail.com   | Abcd Efgh   |
```

Second table "materials" I have a list of materials in which I have two column id and material like shown below:

```
|     id     |     materials    |     
|------------|------------------|
|     1      |      Iron        |  
|------------|------------------|
|     2      |    Plastic       |  
|------------|------------------|
|     3      |     Steel        |
```

Third Table is "categories" in which I have a list of categories id and categories like shown below:

```
|     id     |    categories    |     
|------------|------------------|
|     1      |      chair       |  
|------------|------------------|
|     2      |      Table       |  
|------------|------------------|
|     3      |      Glass       |
```

In the fourth table which named "vendors_materials" I have vendor id, vendor name and material code.

```
|     id     |     name         |    material_cod   |   
|------------|------------------|--------------------
|     1      |    Haris         |           1       | 
|------------|------------------|--------------------
|     1      |    Haris         |           2       | 
|------------|------------------|--------------------
|     3      |    Chris         |           1       |
```

and In the last fifth table which named "vendors_category" I have vendor id, vendor name and category code.

```
|     id     |     name         |    category_cod   |   
|------------|------------------|--------------------
|     2      |    John          |           1       | 
|------------|------------------|--------------------
|     2      |    John          |           2       | 
|------------|------------------|--------------------
|     1      |    Haris         |           1       |
```

I want to get detail of vendor along with materials and categories like shown below:

```
|  id |  name    |      email        |   address   | material    | category    |
|-----|----------|-------------------|-----------------------------------------
|  1  |  Haris   |  Haris@gmail.com  | Abcd Efgh   | Iron plastic|  Chair
|-----|------------------|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  2  |  John    |  john@gmail.com   | Abcd Efgh   |             | Chair table
|-----|------------------|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  3  |  Chris   | chris@gmail.com   | Abcd Efgh   |   Iron      |             |
```

I have done lot of attempts to achieve my results but failed.

Comment: You should look into `JOIN`. However, I would recommend to use the vendor `id` (the primary key) as the foreign key in your `venders_materials` and `vendors_cateories` tables. Numeric primary keys aren't only unique and indexed by default, the look up will be faster as well. Plus, if you see a typo in a vendor name, you won't need to update multiple tables.

Comment: There are also multiple guides/tutorials about this out there if you just do some research. Always start by doing extensive research and make some attempts before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
vendor.name,
vendor.email,
vendor.address,
materials.materials AS material,
categories.categories AS category
FROM vendor 
INNER JOIN vendors_materials ON vendor.name = vendors_category.name
INNER JOIN categories ON vendors_category.category_cod = categories.id
INNER JOIN vendors_materials ON vendors_materials.name = vendor.name
INNER JOIN materials ON materials.id = vendors_materials.material_code
```

also it is not well normalized database structure, first of all it is not recommended to connect tables with varchar columns when you can to connect with ints. For example your 'connector' tables `vendors_materials` and `vendors_category` is connected to `vendor` by `name` when you can connect by `vendor.id`. So your `vendors_materials` table should look like:

```
|     id     |     vendor_id    |    material_cod   |   
|------------|------------------|--------------------
|     1      |    1             |           1       | 
|------------|------------------|--------------------
|     1      |    1             |           2       | 
|------------|------------------|--------------------
|     3      |    3             |           1       |
```

you can do the same in case of `vendors_category`.

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

Actually you need to learn use of JOIN in SQL. If you learn this thing then you will be great to make hard queries.

For reference you can go on : [SQL Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

```
SELECT vendor.name,
       vendor.email,
       vendor.address,
       materials.materials,
       categories.categories
FROM vendor
JOIN materials
JOIN categories
JOIN vendors_materials
JOIN vendors_category ON materials.id = materials.material_cod
AND categories.id = vendors_category.material
AND materials.id = vendor.id
AND vendor.id = categories.id
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: You need to use "JOIN" in proper way. that i have shown to you. IF you will understand join tables then it wiil be easy for you.

Comment: Yes sure.  next time i will make sure of that. I am new to here.

Comment: I know joining the table, but i am not getting accurate results using joins

Comment: Update question and add your query in it. so  we can see what you have tried.